# PhpMyAdmin errors after setting up composer and Valet

Tags: phpmyadmin, laravel-valet

after setting up my laravel dev environment (composer, laravel, laravel/valet) when I open phpMyAdmin it shows some errors. I've tried few solutions from the internet but nothing helps.

That's errors:

```
Warning in ./libraries/classes/Config.php#1681
 mkdir(): Read-only file system

Backtrace

./libraries/classes/Config.php#1681: mkdir(
string '/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/tmp/twig',
integer 504,
boolean true,
)
./libraries/classes/Template.php#60: PhpMyAdmin\Config->getTempDir(string 'twig')
./libraries/classes/Theme.php#103: PhpMyAdmin\Template->__construct()
./libraries/classes/Theme.php#174: PhpMyAdmin\Theme->__construct()
./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#306: PhpMyAdmin\Theme::load(
string './themes/pmahomme',
string '/usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/./themes/pmahomme/',
)
./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#89: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager->loadThemes()
./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#129: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager->__construct()
./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#397: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager::getInstance()
./libraries/common.inc.php#315: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager::initializeTheme()
./index.php#23: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
./../../../../../../../../**home/sanchez/.config/composer/vendor/cpriego/valet-linux/server.php#232: require(./index.php)**
```

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is trying to create a folder and PHP is reporting that the file system is read only. I suppose there's a chance the webserver process simply doesn't have the proper permissions, but in my quick test that gave me a "Permission denied" error instead of "Read-only file system"

In order to build a cache, phpMyAdmin tries to create a folder that by default is in the `tmp/twig` folder. If you need to have phpMyAdmin on a read-only file system, I suggest using the `$cfg['TempDir']` [directive](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_TempDir) to define a more appropriate location for your system.